# Taking pictures from many usb webcams simultaneously

Tags: camera, webcam

I'm looking for software that can take snapshots/pictures from many (about 100) generic USB webcams at the same time for a photogrammetry rig. I've found things like [CaptureGrid](https://kuvacode.com/) which would be perfect, but this product only works with specific models of DSLR cameras.

The software would also need to turn on all of the cameras before taking the snapshot so that they can auto-focus. I don't need to view or record video, and it could run on any OS(though I'd prefer linux).

Comment: Hello! what does `ls /dev/video*` say?

Comment: ls /dev/video lists the cameras and I wrote a simple script that can take pictures sequentially, but there's a ~3 second delay between each picture which is way too slow for what I need to do.

Comment: You need to write a multi-threaded program.  Basically you have one thread of each camera.  Over simplified   for x=1 to 100  beginthread(x)   Now it instantly launches 100 threads.  How long will it take to complete?  I don't know.  Obviously USB bandwidth will be an issue.